# Check succes on laravel orm delete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I have this table with a link to delete

```
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$task->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->name}}</td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="eliminar({{$task->id}})" id="borrar_{{$task->id}}" name="borrar_{{$task->id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

and the javascript code,which made a petition to the destroy method of the controller

```
function eliminar(id){
  var _token = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content');
  $.ajax({

           type: "DELETE",
           url: "task/"+id,
           data: { _token : _token},
           success: function (data) {
              $("#borrar_"+id).closest('tr').fadeOut();
           },
           error: function (data) {
               alert('No se pudo eliminar el resgistro');
           }
    });
}
```

the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Task;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
   .
   .
   .

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
     Task::destroy($id);
}
}
```

when the button is clicked his parent table row fades out ,but I think it's not the best way to do it. How I can check if the `Task::destroy($id)` was made succesfully or not to send a succes o error response to the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $deleted = Task::destroy($id);
    return $deleted ? 'deleted' : 'error';
}
```

In your js:

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data === 'deleted'){
        $("#borrar_"+id).closest('tr').fadeOut();
    }else{
        alert('No se pudo eliminar el resgistro');
    }
},
```

Another method I find useful is the use of findOrFail to get the model, so it returns a 404 if model is not found and ajax go into error response, if the model is found delete method should always return true, so:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
    return $task->delete(); // will return true
}
```

Comment: The 'deleted ' string is not  going to be returned even if the destroy action cannot be done?

Comment: This answer doesn't work in Laravel 7+